# I am having difficulty in generating text classification model

Tags: python, pipeline

I Created a Pipeline and tried to Generate the Model with the data of `all_train_df`(image attached),  but I got ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words.
It is impossible that all `X_train` data is stopwords...

### Pipeline

```
 import string
    from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS
    from spacy.lang.en import English

# Create our list of punctuation marks
punctuations = string.punctuation

# Create our list of stopwords
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
stop_words = spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS

# Load English tokenizer, tagger, parser, NER and word vectors
parser = English()

# Creating our tokenizer function
def spacy_tokenizer(sentence):
    # Creating our token object, which is used to create documents with linguistic annotations.
    mytokens = parser(sentence)

    # Lemmatizing each token and converting each token into lowercase
    mytokens = [ word.lemma_.lower().strip() if word.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else word.lower_ for word in mytokens ]

    # Removing stop words
    mytokens = [ word for word in mytokens if word not in stop_words and word not in punctuations ]

    # return preprocessed list of tokens
    return mytokens


# Custom transformer using spaCy
class predictors(TransformerMixin):
    def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
        # Cleaning Text
        return [clean_text(text) for text in X]

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        return {}

# Basic function to clean the text
def clean_text(text):
    # Removing spaces and converting text into lowercase
    return text.strip().lower()


bow_vector = CountVectorizer(tokenizer = spacy_tokenizer, ngram_range=(1,1),min_df=5, max_df=0.9, stop_words='english', lowercase=True, token_pattern='[a-zA-Z\-][a-zA-Z\-]{2,}')
```

[image]

Comment: nit: `[a-zA-Z\-][a-zA-Z\-]{2,}` is the same as `[a-zA-Z\-]{3,}`

Comment: @Marat Thank you. I just copied the code from others. What does {3,} mean then?

Comment: repeat previous pattern 3 or more times. To the question, the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) say tokenizer is used only when `analyzer=='word'`

Comment: @Marat Thank you!
So, do you mean `def spacy_tokenizer(sentence)` is problem? Should I type               `def spacy_tokenizer(word)` ??

Comment: I have never used spacy and only took a quick glance at the docs. I don't know

Comment: @Marat  I solved the problem thanks to your clue. I put `analyzer='char'` and it works.